# _com_error at memory location

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have mfc application that working fine on the machine with VS 2013 pro. But when I try to run it on the other pc which has VS redistribute package 2013, VS remote tools. Nothing happening. I can see in the task manager that it is started but then it goes away... 
What I have tried so far:
1) I used Dependency Walker to find dll that my application depend on. And for my setup project I add MSVCR120.dll, the rest of the dll's were mfc120.dll the ones that part of the OS i didn't add it them, because I got warnings if I'll add dll which is part of the OS and another PC has exactly the same Windows 7 so they are on the PC.
2) I used VS remote debugger, and at this time I got this First-chance exception .. _com_error at memory location. But I can't catch it. I don't know where to look. My call stack look's that this.
[image]

3) Last out put before error, says that sqloledb.rll was not loaded, I check it systems folder does have it, I even copied to the folder where application executable located, still does not loaded, still have exception.

Can any one point me to what can cause this error or why application does not run? What else to install so my application can run the same way it is run on the machine with VS. It is seems that this error rise often but none of the solution helped me.

I used procmon.exe and it is shows buffer overflow. 
[image]

It is turn out to be database connection. Application quite on this line, so I add try/catch block. But shows "unexpected error"...

```
m_pAppConn->Open("File Name=MyData.udl", "", "", adConnectUnspecified);
```

m_pAppConn is a _ConnectionPtr. On my pc I have MS SQl Server Enterprise, but on target pc MS SQL Express, could it be the issue?

Comment: Getting a _com_error exception is entirely normal.  Standard behavior when you use #import in your code and a COM call failed.  Of course you can catch it, you just don't know where to put it as long as the stack trace you get is this miserable.  You need the .pdb for the program to make it more readable.  Write defensive code and *assume* that a COM call can fail.  They always do, eventually.

Comment: You can try using procmon.exe from sysinternals to trace all file accesses of Calibration.exe. When it's looking for some dll and can't find it, it's pretty obvious from that log. You'll see where it was looking for them and what happened (of course, given that it's the dll which was not found is the problem)

Comment: Also, check return code of your application, event log, and you can use windbg (or gflags) to get a crash dump (if application crashes) and then analyze it.

Comment: Could it be happening because on my pc I am using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit), but on the target machine Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit)??